# множество процессов после сборки скрипта auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, tkinter, threading, auto-py-to-exe

Пишу программу пинга нескольких серверов, написал с помощью pysimplegui и собрал с помощью auto-py-to-exe - всё работает.
Решил переписать на tkinter. В pycharm всё работает, но после сборки получаю множественные процессы
Подскажите направление куда копать?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
import datetime

import subprocess
global thread_stop
def do_ping_in_loop(main_canvas,id):
    fin_th = open('conf.txt', 'rt')
    items_th = fin_th.readlines()
    fin_th.close()
    len_th = len(items_th)
    mas_change = [1 for i in range(len_th)]
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
        ii = 0
        while ii < len_th:
            if thread_stop:
                return
            response = subprocess.call("ping -n 1 " + items_th[ii], shell=True)
            print(response)
            if response != 0:
                print(response)
                # graph2 = windows.Element('graph'+str(ii))
                current_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
                current_time_date = datetime.datetime.today().isoformat()
                if mas_change[ii]:
                    with open(items_th[ii].replace('.', '_').replace('\n', '') + '-' + str(current_date) + '.txt',
                              'a') as file:
                        file.write(f'{current_time_date} Сервер не доступен! \n')
                    mas_change[ii] = 0
                main_canvas[ii].itemconfigure(id[ii], fill="red")
            else:
                # graph2 = windows.Element('graph'+str(ii))
                current_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
                current_time_date = datetime.datetime.today().isoformat()
                if not mas_change[ii]:
                    with open(items_th[ii].replace('.', '_').replace('\n', '') + '-' + str(current_date) + '.txt',
                              'a') as file:
                        file.write(f'{current_time_date} Сервер доступен! \n')
                    mas_change[ii] = 1
                main_canvas[ii].itemconfigure(id[ii], fill="green")
                # graph.DrawImage(filename="foo.png", location=(0, 400))
                # graph2.DrawRectangle((5, 5), (20, 20), line_color="green", fill_color='green')
            ii += 1
            sleep(1)
file_not_found=False
try:
    fin = open('conf.txt', 'rt')
    items = fin.readlines()
    fin.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    file_not_found=True
root = Tk()
root.title("Тестовый пинг")
if not file_not_found:
    len_ip=len(items)
    max_len_of_items=0
    for item in items:
        if len(item)>max_len_of_items:
            max_len_of_items=len(item)
    win_width=max_len_of_items * 10 + 250
    win_height=len_ip * 50
    root.geometry(str(win_width)+"x"+str(win_height))
    # max_len_of_items * 5 + 250, len_ip * 40
    i=0
    id_rectangle=[0 for i in range(len_ip)]
    red = "red"
    green = "green"
    canvases = [Canvas(bg="white", width=20, height=20) for count in range(len_ip)]
    while i < len_ip:
        Label(text=items[i], font=("Arial", 14)).place(x=10, y=i*30+30)
        # canvas = Canvas(bg="white", width=20, height=20)
        canvases[i].place(x=max_len_of_items*20+30, y=i*30+30)

        id_rectangle[i] = canvases[i].create_rectangle(0, 0, 200, 60, fill="red", outline="red")

        i+=1
    #label.place()
    thread_stop=False
    th = Thread(target=do_ping_in_loop, args=(canvases,id_rectangle),daemon=True)
    th.start()
else:
    count_label=0
    text = ['Отсутствует файл conf.txt в папке с программой.',
            'Добавьте файл и перезапустите программу',
            'Синтаксис файла:',
            'каждый сервер который необходимо',
            'пинговать пишется с новой строки. Например:',
            'ya.ru',
            '172.25.48.97']
    while count_label<7:
        Label(text=text[count_label], font=("Arial", 14)).place(x=10, y=count_label*30+30)
        count_label+=1
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Так, а в чём вопрос то? Вы используете библиотеку threading что бы порождать процессы, а в итоге жалуетесь на это?

Comment: Что означает "множественные процессы"? В коде я вижу, что вы используете субпроцесс, это буквально создание нового процесса. К комментарию выше, threading не порожает процессы.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо!
Похоже, дело в определённой структуре проекта при работе с `Tkinter` и `Threading`.

Переписал всё вот так, и заработало:

```
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import datetime

import subprocess
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        file_not_found = False
        try:
            fin = open('conf.txt', 'rt')
            items = fin.readlines()
            fin.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            file_not_found = True
        if not file_not_found:
            len_ip = len(items)
            max_len_of_items = 0
            for item in items:
                if len(item) > max_len_of_items:
                    max_len_of_items = len(item)
            win_width = max_len_of_items * 10 + 250
            win_height = len_ip * 50

            self.geometry(str(win_width) + "x" + str(win_height))
            # max_len_of_items * 5 + 250, len_ip * 40
            i = 0
            self.id_rectangle = [0 for i in range(len_ip)]
            red = "red"
            green = "green"

            self.canvases = [tk.Canvas(bg="white", width=20, height=20) for count in range(len_ip)]
            while i < len_ip:
                tk.Label(text=items[i], font=("Arial", 14)).place(x=10, y=i * 30 + 30)
                # canvas = Canvas(bg="white", width=20, height=20)
                self.canvases[i].place(x=max_len_of_items * 20 + 30, y=i * 30 + 30)

                self.id_rectangle[i] = self.canvases[i].create_rectangle(0, 0, 200, 60, fill="red", outline="red")

                i += 1
            # label.place()
            thread_stop = False
            # th = Thread(target=do_ping_in_loop, daemon=True)
            # th.start()
        # self.button = tk.Button(self, command=self.start_action,
        #                         text="Ждать 5 секунд")
        # self.button.pack(padx=50, pady=20)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_action,daemon=True)
        print(threading.main_thread().name)
        print(thread.name)
        thread.start()

    def start_action(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        #self.check_thread(thread)

    def check_thread(self, thread):
        if thread.is_alive():
            self.after(100, lambda: self.check_thread(thread))
        else:
            self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def run_action(self):
        fin_th = open('conf.txt', 'rt')
        items_th = fin_th.readlines()
        fin_th.close()
        len_th = len(items_th)
        mas_change = [1 for i in range(len_th)]
        a = 1
        while a == 1:
            ii = 0
            while ii < len_th:
                # if thread_stop:
                #     return
                response = subprocess.call("ping -n 1 " + items_th[ii], shell=True)
                print(response)
                if response != 0:
                    print(response)
                    # graph2 = windows.Element('graph'+str(ii))
                    current_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
                    current_time_date = datetime.datetime.today().isoformat()
                    if mas_change[ii]:
                        with open(items_th[ii].replace('.', '_').replace('\n', '') + '-' + str(current_date) + '.txt',
                                  'a') as file:
                            file.write(f'{current_time_date} Сервер не доступен! \n')
                        mas_change[ii] = 0
                    self.canvases[ii].itemconfigure(self.id_rectangle[ii], fill="red")
                else:
                    # graph2 = windows.Element('graph'+str(ii))
                    current_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
                    current_time_date = datetime.datetime.today().isoformat()
                    if not mas_change[ii]:
                        with open(items_th[ii].replace('.', '_').replace('\n', '') + '-' + str(current_date) + '.txt',
                                  'a') as file:
                            file.write(f'{current_time_date} Сервер доступен! \n')
                        mas_change[ii] = 1
                    self.canvases[ii].itemconfigure(self.id_rectangle[ii], fill="green")
                    # graph.DrawImage(filename="foo.png", location=(0, 400))
                    # graph2.DrawRectangle((5, 5), (20, 20), line_color="green", fill_color='green')
                ii += 1
                sleep(1)
        # print("Запуск длительного действия...")
        # time.sleep(5)
        # print("Длительное действие завершено!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```